# Importing / copying data from PostGIS to ArcGIS / ArcMAP

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, import, geometric-network, copy

So, I'm working on a project using Postgresql and Postgis. We have a client using ArcGIS (10.0) and ArcFM. We are trying to export some data from postgres to ESRI, but we have our hands tied quite a bit as we don't have esri experience or access to esri!

The client is a utility and using the connectivity features of esri. They have a pretty extensive network mapped already and we are looking to add assets to it. For example, a service line to an existing water main - and have it connected appropriately.

We have looked at a few ways so far, I thought the most promising was to use gdal / ogr to export from postgres to a file geodatabase. Then the 'Geometric Network Incremental Loader' could be used to import and connect the data. It may still work but it seems that the likely SRID projection needed isn't supported by the ogr / FileGDB format.

Doing more research, I found that arcgis has capabilities to read postgis - it seems at both the server and desktop level. Is it possible then for ArcGIS to load postgis data and import / copy either all or selected data from the postgis 'layer' in to the existing geometric network? Copying all the attributes, geometries and connecting appropriately? I saw reference to the 'Copy Features' command - will this do all of that?

Answer (score 3):

If you have PostGIS installed, you will be able to read the database the same way as you would read an SDE-enabled/"Enterprise" geodatabase that uses ESRI's st_geometry libraries instead of PostGIS.

Create a new database connection, specify the server name, database name, and the user credentials, and you should be good to go. You can create a new database connection by going to "Database Connections" in your Catalog tree or browsing to a file folder (under Folder Connections) and right clicking within the folder, clicking New > Database Connection.

I have used PostGIS + ArcGIS on several projects and there are some quirks. Also, I believe 10.2 may be the earliest version that will support connecting to PostGIS and reading the PostGIS tables. [You may also have to install the third party libraries to enable PostgreSQL connectivity within ArcGIS.](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/database-requirements-postgresql.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E08607BD999F4249B0DC65B8B0287433) And you'll likely want to install both the 32- and 64-bit versions, as Desktop will use 32-bit, but if you hand off the execution to Background Processing and have the 64-bit processing installed, it will fail because the drivers cannot be found. ArcGIS with PostGIS will not support geometric networks within the database, as that's functionality reserved for an SDE/"Enterprise" database.

Comment: Cool, sounds promising. I do see that [10.0 recognizes postgis](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_the_PostGIS_geometry_type/002p0000006t000000/).

It looks like [copy and paste](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#/Copying_and_pasting_features/001t00000072000000/) should allow pasting features to the SDE database and handle connectivity rules properly as well.